# Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать такую штуку?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: пример]

Нужно сделать такой бар, не могу понять, как сделать шкалу прогресса круглой?

Comment: с помощью svg можно

Comment: Опишите более детально как вы это пытались сделать? Добавьте пример кода https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Anna, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amrIqeOXQW0 посмотрите этот ролик. Возможно, это то что вам надо

Comment: @Listopad02 спасибо большое, то, что надо!